# Change the css class of custom component from another component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

I mocked up a very small example of my problem here: https://github.com/lovefamilychildrenhappiness/AngularCustomComponentValidation

I have a custom component, which encapsulates an input field. The formControl associated with this input field has `Validators.required` (it is a required field). Inside the custom component, I have an `onChange` event which is fired when text is entered. I check if field is empty; if so, I add css class using `ngClass`. I also have set the `registerOnChange` of `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR`, so I notify the form when the input changes. Finally, I implement `NG_VALIDATORS` interface to make the formControl invalid or valid.

My problem is I have a button that is clicked (it's not the submit button). When this button is clicked, I need to check if the custom component is blank or not, and if it is, change the css class and make the form invalid. I think the `validate` method of `NG_VALIDATORS` is doing that. But I need to change the css class of customComponent so background turns red. I spend severals hours on this and cannot figure it out:

```
// my-input.component.html
<textarea
 [value]="value" 
 (input)="onChange($event.target.value)"
 [ngClass]="{'failed-validation' : this.validationError }">
</textarea>

// my-input.component.ts

  validate(control: FormControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    if(!this.validationError){
      return null
    } else {
      return { required: true };
    }
  }


  private onChange(val) {

    if(val.length > 0) {
        this.value = val
        this.validationError = false;
    } else {
        this.validationError = true;
    }

    // update the form
    this.propagateChange(val);
 }

// app.component.html
<form [formGroup]="reactiveForm">
  <app-my-input formControlName="result"></app-my-input>
  <input 
    value="Submit"
    (click)="nextStep($event)"
    type="button">
</form>


// app.component.ts

  private nextStep(event){
    // How do I dynamically change the class of the form control so I can change the style if formControl invalid when clicking the nextStep button
    // pseudocode:
    // if( !this.reactiveForm.controls['result'].valid ){
    //  this.reactiveForm.controls['result'].addClass('failed-validation');
    // }
  }
```

How can I get the css of the formControl to change in another component?

Comment: Can't you add required attribute to textarea ?

Comment: @Chellappanவ and how would I ensure the background color changes when the button is clicked?

Comment: @Chellappanவ adding validationError to writeValue will make the background red before the user even types into the form control. Also, since I reuse this custom component among different FormControls, the FormControls which do not have any validation would now have a background color of red.

Comment: Basically all I am asking is how do I dynamically change the css style of a custom component from another component. This is something that can easily be achieved in React or jQuery.

Comment: I will have a look and let you know

Comment: @Chellappanவ I await any feedback. Already spent 5 hours on this feverishly scurrying through the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you using reactive form I have modified your custom form control. Here I have Use Injected NgControl Which is base class for all FormControl-based directives extend.

**Try this:**

```
import { Component, Input, forwardRef, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import {
  ControlValueAccessor,
  NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  NgControl,
  NG_VALIDATORS,
  FormControl,
  ValidationErrors,
  Validator
} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: "app-my-input",
  templateUrl: "./my-input.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./my-input.component.scss"]
})
export class MyInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit {
  private propagateChange = (_: any) => {};
  value = "";
  onTouch: () => void;

  constructor(public controlDir: NgControl) {
    controlDir.valueAccessor = this;
  }
  writeValue(value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn) {
    this.onTouch = fn;
  }
  onChange(value) {
    this.propagateChange(value);
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    const control = this.controlDir.control;
    control.setValidators([control.validator ? control.validator : null]);
    control.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
}
```

> [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-pfntcd)

[For More Information Forms Check this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CD_t3m2WMM8)

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of this line of code: controlDir.valueAccessor = this; Why do we need to assign 'this' to controlDir.valueAccessor?

Comment: Also, I noticed you removed the validator() method. I thought that was needed to determine whether the custom component was valid or not. If it's not needed, then what is the purpose of this validator() method?

Comment: Instead of registering custom element with providers array we have used ngControl to register

Comment: The only thing is my original form when you add input to form and then remove the input, it highlights background as red because the form was touched and not valid. In your solution, that functionality was removed.

Comment: On the onChange callback inside the custom component, I added this: if(val.length === 0) {
      this.controlDir.control.markAllAsTouched();
    }. And it seems to have worked. Is this the best approach?

Comment: It's okay to trigger markAllAsTouched() manually depend on your requirement.